# Visual Studio Add-in not going away

Tags: visual-studio

Ok, so I demo'd Refactor Pro and Resharper, I'm more comfortable with Resharper so that's what I bought. When I uninstalled Refactor Pro I thought everything was breezy. However, now when I open Visual Studio I get

The Add-in 'DevExpress Tools' failed to load or caused and exception, woudl you like to remove this Add in?

If you choose yes, the file it was loaded from,

> 'C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins\DevExpressToolsOrcas.Addin' will be renamed.

I hit yes, then get:

> "Could Not rename Add-in file "C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins\DevExpressToolsOrcas.Addin"

This happens every time, I went to that location and there is not folder by that name. I searched for that file and nothing.

Anyone experience a clingy add-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with the VS.NET 2005 version and I'm not sure it is related. It was a registry problem and when i contacted the people from devexpress they send me a clean up tool.

You can try to see if there is another clean up tool for 2008 or search in the registry for the file name and remove it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This page has instructions on how to manually remove a Visual Studio add-in:

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006018.aspx